# Trying to paste the search parameters to new url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, search, parameters

I am trying to paste the search parameters of my old url to another url.

A url would look something like this:
https://demo.url.io/onlineberatung?filter=Tasting%2CSekt+%26+Co&money=Kleiner+Geldbeutel

This is the code that I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".money").forEach(function(e) {
        e.addEventListener("click", function() {
            myfunction();
        });
    });
});
var urlParams = window.location.search;

//create a function that links me to the page /test/
function myfunction() {
    window.location.href = "/test/" + urlParams;
}
```

After I click on the class .money it should redirect me the new page: `demo.url.io/test?filter=Tasting%2CSekt+%26+Co&money=Kleiner+Geldbeutel`

Currently it's only bringing me to the new page but without the query parameters.

I would like to try solving it with JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Correct, I fixed that. Thanky you @GrafiCode

Comment: This is a question better answered by your browser's debugger.  Step through the code and watch the variables.

Comment: @Yogi It is giving me the parameters in the console: var urlParams = window.location.search; console.log(urlParams)
?filter=Tasting%2CSekt+%26+Co&money=Kleiner+Geldbeutel

Comment: put console.log(urlParams) inside myfunction.

Comment: @James, thank you very much this solved the issue! The variable has to be in the function, that was a pretty obvious mistake. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Well, no.  You *can* declare variables like urlParams in global scope, like you had, and as long as the function (myfunction) doesn't declare its own urlParams, accessing urlParams will give you the value of the global.  However, other functions and code can modify urlParams too.  I was thinking you had some code that cleared urlParams somewhere, and by calling console.log(urlParams) inside myfunction, you could see an empty string.  However, I'm glad you found a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

The Variable has to be in the function and not outside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".money").forEach(function(e) {
        e.addEventListener("click", function() {
            myfunction();
        });
    });
});


//create a function that links me to the page /test/
function myfunction() {
var urlParams = window.location.search;

    window.location.href = "/test/" + urlParams;
}
```